# How can I apply the "get caption" function to every row in a column?

Tags: r, youtube, apply, transcription

I created a data frame in R where column 2 holds a URL I extracted from YouTube in every row. Downloaded the youtubecaption package and would like to apply the "get_caption()" function to every row in the column with URLs. This is because I would like to transcript the audio from every URL I collected.

I tried to create a function to automate this by doing the following:

```
# Extracts the URLs from the page with the playlist of YouTube Videos
ExtractTranscript <- function(){
  # Extract the Transcripts
  Transcripts <- get_caption()%>%
  return(data_frame(Transcript = Transcripts))
}
```

And then I tried to use the apply function to use get caption on every url in the column:

```
apply(YouTubeUrls,2, ExtractTranscript)
```

However, it didn't work. Do you have any advice? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The following should get all the captions and store into a list.

```
captions <- sapply(YouTubeUrls[,2], FUN = get_caption)
```

This is from the 'family' of apply functions in R. It iterates (like a for loop) over a list/vector, in this case column 2 of your dataframe, and applies the get_caption function. It will then store the captions found from the youtube video in a list. You should then be able to access the tibbles which stores the actual captions using standard list, such as:

```
 captions[[1]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!!! This seems to have worked to a certain degree. So I really appreciate the step forward!!! One thing: it will only read the first row of the column for some reason. Thoughts?

Comment: One step at a time I suppose. Can you provide a small sample of the input data, and then a sample of the captions you are getting back? It will help find the error if I can see a sample of data.

Comment: Sorry I should've included the error! This is the error it spits out: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedRegistered S3 method overwritten by 'dplyr':
  method           from
  print.rowwise_df